# Java ServerSocket connection not working in school network

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, firewall

I've got a working ServerSocket client and server program. The server is running on a home server on a port above 1024, with port forwarding a am able to access it from outside my LAN. 
But when I try to connect to the running server from my school network (which allows me to access the internet over HTTP(s)) the client program is able to get the IP address from the domain but not to connect the server. I just get an timed out exception.
I use normal ServerSocket and Socket Java classes.

I assume the problem is caused by firewall or proxy restrictions that limit the connections to the outside of our local school network.

Are there any easy ways to solve this problems?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your assumption that it is a firewall is likely accurate - that is the reason firewalls exist - to protect servers from undesirable connections on ports they do not wish accessed. You can work with your school network tech to open the necessary firewall port. Otherwise you are probably out of luck.

Comment: I can't ask my teacher (the network administrator) because he would not support my plan xD